# .NET Framework compatibilty with Oracle version

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, migration, odac

We have to migrate from Oracle 11g to Oracle 19c.
Our .NET apps are in 4.0 or 4.5 NET Framework.

Will these .NET versions still be compatible with the oracle driver (ODAC) 19c ? If not, what version of .NET do I need? And with which version of visual studio ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET Core, Managed, and Unmanaged Drivers 19c are certified with .NET Framework 4.8.

You need .NET Framework 4.8

ODP.NET Core 19.5 is certified with .NET Core 3.

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (ODT) is a tightly integrated extension for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2017.

[ODP.NET](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html)

[ODAC 19c Data Sheet](https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/collateral/odac-19c-release-1-data-sheet.pdf)

Comment: Thank you ! Is there an impact on the version of SQL Developer (19.1 currently) ?

Comment: No impact from my experience. I've ODAC 19c and I've recently upgraded SQL Developer 19.1 to 19.2 and no isseu before or now.

Comment: I don't think you need .NET Framework 4.8, every version > 4.0 should be fine.

Comment: Is there a Microsoft webpage where I can verify it ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see also in another webpage "ODP.NET 19c prend en charge Entity Framework Core, .NET Framework 4.8".

Comment: You can try create a test project and add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget. I've just created several projects with different version of .net framework (4.0,4.5,4.7.2 and 4.8) and was able to install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and connect to DB.