# Transaction error when connecting to Oracle 19c with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle, transactionscope, odp.net-managed, mts

When connecting to some databases, I get the following error message when opening a connection.
The caller is a `TransactionScope`.

From the app:

```
MTSRMManager.CCPEnlistDistributedTxnToSysTxn(OracleConnectionImpl connImpl, Transaction txn, MTSTxnRM txnRM, MTSTxnBranch txnBranch)
MTSRMManager.CCPEnlistTransaction(OracleConnectionImpl connImpl, Transaction transaction, MTSTxnRM txnRM, MTSTxnBranch txnBranch)
PoolManager`3.GetEnlisted(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
OracleConnection.Open()
```

From the Oracle.DataManagesAccess trace :

```
2021-12-23 16:55:32.568831 TID:12  (PRI) (EXT) (MTS) PSPEManager.Promote() Local TxnID = 2c5401a0-d202-4269-b095-e668f72bbfbb:1TxnID = 149102f3-5961-45ef-be45-7ece3bfefd4f
2021-12-23 16:55:32.591837 TID:12  (PRI) (ENT) MTSRMManager.HandleException()
2021-12-23 16:55:32.603931 TID:12  (PRI) (ERR) (MTS) MTSRMManager.HandleException() (txnid=2c5401a0-d202-4269-b095-e668f72bbfbb:1) (DUMP)(txnid=2c5401a0-d202-4269-b095-e668f72bbfbb:1) (service name=sys$users) (pmid=38945919)[(count:0)] System.InvalidOperationException: L'opération n'est pas valide dans l'état actuel de l'inscription.
   at System.Transactions.EnlistmentState.InternalAborted(InternalEnlistment enlistment)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetTransmitterPropagationToken(Transaction transaction)
   at OracleInternal.MTS.MTSRMManager.CCPEnlistDistributedTxnToSysTxn(OracleConnectionImpl connImpl, Transaction txn, MTSTxnRM txnRM, MTSTxnBranch txnBranch)
```

Some work just fine.

I've tried enabling some of these settings with no luck

```
<setting name="LegacyTransactionBindingBehavior" value="1"/>
<setting name="PromotableTransaction" value="Promotable" />
<setting name="DynamicEnlistment" value="1" />
<setting name="Pooling" value="false"/>
```

We're migrating code previously accessing Oracle 11g to Oracle 19c.

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.4.0. Same problem happens with 19.13.0

Comment: [New ODP.NET Features by Oracle Release Version](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/new-dotnet-features.html), [.NET Framework compatibilty with Oracle version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65287549/net-framework-compatibilty-with-oracle-version), [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html), [.NET Development with ODAC](https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/collateral/odac-19c-release-1-data-sheet.pdf), [Oracle Data Provider for .NET Assembly](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/intro003.htm#BHCJFIAJ)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3.2/